# SagePay Ebizmarts Test Transaction Error

Tags: jquery, magento, opayo

I've asked about this over at ebizmarts support forums... but I haven't received any sort of help as of yet.

I'm going through the SagePay set up process and I'm at the stage where I need to put through a test transaction using Sage's provided test card details (http://www.sagepay.co.uk/support/12/36/test-card-details-for-your-test-transactions).

I'm using Ebizmart's free Sage extension along with MageApps SuperCheckout.

When trying to submit the transaction, all I get is a popup saying:

```
Payment has failed, please reload checkout page and try again. Your card has not been charged.
```

The is one javascript error when I inspect:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: changecsvclass is not defined
```

This error only happens after I click Place Order.

I am using jQuery no conflict, however taking this out didn't fix anything.

The dev site is at http://metrofurniture.seolution.co.uk/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

SagePay and Ebizmarts both have very good support. I think if you are patient they will hep you get to the bottom of the issue.

It could be a SagePay misconfiguration but it looks like a clash between SuperCheckout and Ebizmarts. You can test that by using the standard checkout instead of SuperCheckout.

To start debugging, look at the POST urls and inspect the code in the controllers that are being called. See image below for details. I mean, from the POST URLs we can deduce you should read the functions `placeOrderAction()` and `orderSaveAction()` in the file `app/code/[community or local]/mageapps/supercheckout/controllers/IndexController.php`

[image: failed payment POST details]